# Would type erasure occur here?

Tags: java, exception, generics

I think I'll lose information on the specific type of Exception in this block of code.  How can I preserve the type of Exception so that I don't have to add a generic Exception throws clause to the method that contains the following code?  I think it's got to do with employing [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) correctly; guidance would be appreciated.

```
for( int i = 0; i < retries; i ++ ) {
    Exception anyException = null;
    try {
        Future<Object> returnedObj = threadPool.submit(task);
        toReturn = returnedObj.get(timeout, timeunit);
        break;
    } catch (RejectedExecutionException ex) {
        anyException = ex;
    } catch (NullPointerException ex ) {
        anyException = ex;
    }
    ...
    finally {
       ...
       if(i == retries -1 && anyException != null) {
           throw anyException;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not what type erasure is, and there's nothing regarding generics when it comes to the exception.

Comment: You can always later use `instanceof` to get the type, but I don't get why you would catch them in the first place, if you want to throw them again.

Comment: type erasure in Java has a specific meaning, related to generic types : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html
this is not related.

Comment: I want to catch them so I can explicitly clean up some things prior to re-throwing them.  @DaveNewton, thanks for the clarification; I need to read the generics tutorial.  I believe the finally would executed even after re-throwing the same exception in a given catch clause, though, I don't want to re-throw right away - I want to retry the try block a given number of times, keeping track of the last (or all) exception(s) to occur and wrap that in a custom MaxRetriesFailed and then throw that.

Comment: Test anyException with instanceof, and cast it to one of the two specific exception types before throwing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do :

```
try {
    Future<Object> returnedObj = threadPool.submit(task);
    toReturn = returnedObj.get(timeout, timeunit);
    break;
} catch (Exception ex) {
   if(i == retries -1) {
       throw ex;
   }
```

catch the first N exceptions, and only rethrow the last one.
Catching and rethrowing it like this won't lose any type information.  Catching it by the base class 'Exception' just means you don't have to repeat the same code for every possible type.  But if you want to avoid 'throws Exception' on your method - then yes you will need multiple catch / rethrows for each type.  As someone pointed out - the ones you catch currently are not checked, so you can happily throw them without having to declare it in your method signature.

I should say it's not a good idea to just swallow exceptions like this.
At the very least log them somewhere...

Answer (score 3):

May I just mention that your code is severely broken. *Never throw from the finally block*. If your try-block throws any other exception besides those two you catch explicitly, you are running a risk that this exception will be masked and the *anyException* thrown instead. This will create bugs of such stealth that a team member might want to plan a vendetta on you.

As for the type of your exceptions, they are both unchecked, so they will not give you any trouble regarding method signature. Just throw them without declaring.

Comment: You are right - finally is not where you throw.  I ended up adding a clause for the most exclusive Throwable, after logging the less inclusive ones.  I retry in most cases, except one so far.  So, I initially put the check for reaching the retry limit in the finally.  I've now put it outside of the finally, but before the for loop ends.  My question is now: does a finally get executed necessarily even after throwing a new exception in one or some or all of the catch blocks above it?

Comment: Yes, it gets executed *always*, whatever the course of events, and always as the last thing in the whole try-catch-finally block. So if you throw from catch, and then `finally` throws something else, that something else will be thrown. If `finally` does a `return`, there will be no exception thrown at all.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with generic code, but with an overly broad local variable type.

```
throw anyException;
```

throws a generic `Exception` because the type of `anyException` is just `Exception` so your method will need to declare `throws Exception` which is probably overly broad.

The simplest solution is probably to put

```
if(i == retries -1) {
  throw ex;
}
```

inside each catch block, or rework the contents of the `try` block so there are fewer kinds of exceptions that might result in a retry.

Do you really want to retry on anything other than a failure due to a transient problem like network congestion?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (anyException instanceOf RejectedExecutionException) {
  throw (RejectedExecutionException) anyException;
}
else if (anyException instanceof NullPointerException) {
  throw (NullPointerException) anyException;
}
```

Comment: (But it does get a little hairy throwing an exception from `finally` (I don't recall all of the issues).  Better to call a common routine for "cleanup" from your `catch` clauses and then return and rethrow the exception.)

Comment: do the multiple catch blocks each need a call to the cleanup routine, if the finally necessarily gets executed (even if there is a new exception thrown in one of those catch blocks?)

Comment: You are correct in observing that you can simply decide to resignal or not in the catch blocks (or signal a new exception there), and the `finally` code will get executed to perform cleanup (after the exception is rethrown).  It's throwing an exception from the finally block that confuses things -- it can be done, but there are caveats that I can't remember.